# Replace 1 line in multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing

I have some text files inside one directory. They all have many different strings, but 1 string is same for all.

```
Acct-Session-Id = "XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX"
```

where X - symbol in HEX-format.

I need to replace this ID in all these files with random XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX number. Number must be the same in all files. After replacinf, files must be saved with same names.

I tried to do this with sed, but it didn't work...

Comment: show us your sed. line is exact whole line (length, spaces)? replacement is random generated valid hex string, given hex string, or just chars X?

Comment: Line is exact whole line. Always starts with Acct-Session-Id(space)=(space)"XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX". So it's lengh is always the same.

Replacement is just 16 chars X (8 chars X, then - then 8 chars X), each from 1 to F (HEX symbols).

I tried to solve this task with other similar topics about sed on this forum, but it isn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with `Linux`, and assuming you meant GNU/Linux, you could write a script like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
IFS= read -r uuid < /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid || exit
id=${uuid%-*-*}
id=${id%-*}${id##*-}

grep -rl --null -e 'Acct-Session-Id = ".*"' -- "$@" |
  xargs -r0 sed -i -e 's/\(Acct-Session-Id = \)"[^"]*"/\1"'"$id"'"/g' --
```

To be invoked as:

```
path/to/that-script path/to/dir-or-file path/to/other/dir-or-file...
```

Comment: Thank for your answer! If i want to change with this script, for example, file3.txt, can I just add "file3.txt" to the last string of your script? Because I did it, and it not worked. File stays the same.

Comment: @TimofeyPasichnik, you'd call that script with as argument the list of directory or files where you want the substitution to be done.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, now it work, but inserts more characters that I want.

    # cat file1.txt
    First string
    Acct-Session-Id = "1234ABCD-5678EFAB"
    Third string
    # ./newscript2.sh file1.txt
    # cat file1.txt
    First string
    Acct-Session-Id = "b1093758-ba69-4cd3-b56e2989228e8bfe"
    Third string

Comment: @TimofeyPasichnik, sorry my bad, there was (were?) a couple of typos in that code. See edit.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas now it works like a charm :) Thanks alot!

Answer (score 4):

Like this, using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
id=$(openssl rand -hex 8 | sed 's/./-&/9')
awk -v id=$id '$1 == "Acct-Session-Id"{$3="\042"id"\042"}1' file
```

### Output

```
Acct-Session-Id = "f7ea78e0-1eeb7b09"
```

Then:

```
id=$(openssl rand -hex 8 | sed 's/./-&/9')

while IFS= read -r f; do
    awk -v id=$id '$1 == "Acct-Session-Id"{$3="\042"id"\042"}1' "$f" > /tmp/tmp$$
    mv /tmp/tmp$$ "$f"
done < <(grep -l 'Acct-Session-Id' .)
```

---

Another solution, using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) (no need loop and temporary files):

```
export id=$(openssl rand -hex 8 | sed 's/./-&/9')

perl -i -lane '
    $F[2] = "\042$ENV{id}\042" if $F[0] eq "Acct-Session-Id";
    print join " ", @F
' files*
```

Answer (score 0):

one-liner with sed

```
id=$(hexdump -vn8 -e '4/1 "%02x" "-"' /dev/urandom);
sed -ri 's,^Acct-Session-Id = "[[:xdigit:]]{8}-[[:xdigit:]]{8}"$,Acct-Session-Id = "'"${id%?}"'",' ./*.txt;
```

`cat /dev/urandom` will output random bytes
`hexdump` will print hex view of files
`-v` = do not supress empty bytes
`-n <length>` = only first n bytes (same like head -c)
`-e 4/1` will output 4 bytes x 1 per line with format `%02x` (2 digits) and lines separated with `-`
so the value of `id` should be something like `cf41f825-8b1e4c1c-` (with trailing `-` unfortunately)

`sed -i` ./*.txt will edit all files in place
`'s,^find$,'replace','` will search for word *'find'* at `^` start of line, and
line must terminated `$` right after word (matches exact whole line)
`'replace'` must unquoted in between in order to parse the variable
(`"$id"` wouldn't evaluated within single quotes)

you can delele `^` and `$` if you want to match all strings

`[[:xdigit:]]` will match one single byte between `0-f` hex digit (thx @GillesQuenot)
`{8}` previous byte must exist 8x times in series

`${id%?}` will output `$id` with string manipulation
`%` remove shortest occurrence if present at end
`?` wildcard for any single byte
so replacement id is something like `cf41f825-8b1e4c1c`

---

in this example only the 1. + 3. line is matching your request and will be changed, other lines remain untouched

[image: screenshot]

`sed` only replaces when line is exact line, `XXX` is a valid hex string and embedded in double quotes `"..."` it leave the line untouched if there are additional spaces or any other chars. the word `Acct-Session-Id` is case-sensitive. the file name(s) are passed as last argument `./*.txt` and lines are replaced in place `-i`

Comment: + useless use of `cat`, and `[0-9A-Fa-f]` can be simplified with POSIX class

Comment: `[[:xdigit:]]` class

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do I understand correctly, that I need to put this sed inside echo and then >> filename? because when I execute this command, inside sh script or just in terminal, nothing happens and files stay the same...

Comment: i have switched the flags `-r` `-i` because `-ir` is not same as `-ri` now it should work sorry